# Scrapy - Passing Parameters In URLs

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, scrapy, python-requests

If we use `requests` and we need Passing Parameters In URLs we can use `params`

```
import requests


params = (
    ('q', 'scrapy'),
)

response = requests.get('https://github.com/search', params=params)
```

response.url will be

```
In [4]: response.url                                                                                                                                            
Out[4]: 'https://github.com/search?q=scrapy'
```

https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
But how Passing Parameters In URLs if we use Scrapy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need use `FormRequest` with GET method and pass `params` in `formdata`

```
        return FormRequest(url='https://github.com/search',
                           method='GET',
                           headers=headers,
                           formdata=params,
                           callback=self.parse_data)
```